# How to call PHP property from string stored in a Variable

Tags: php, laravel, maatwebsite-excel, dynamic-variables, laravel-excel

I'm using maatwebsite/excel package and I would like to dynamically pass different file type as a second parameter.
[See function here](https://laravel-excel.maatwebsite.nl/3.1/exports/export-formats.html)  
Below is the variable:

```
$fileType = $request->input('fileType', 'xlsx');
$writerType = Excel::$fileType;
```

But I get the error:

> Access to undeclared static property: Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::$fileType

I try to use curly brackets but doesn't work:

```
Excel::${"fileType"};
```

How do I pass the variable? Thanks!

Comment: so you want the value of $fileType to be the property name? like `Excel::xlsx`? What's the value of `$fileType`?

Comment: how is your Excel's static variable declared ?

Comment: Why don't you use the variable `$fileType` without `Excel::`?

Comment: @Jeff Yes, the $fileType will be 'xlsx' or 'csv'.

Comment: @gogaz This is maatwebsite/excel package.
https://laravel-excel.maatwebsite.nl/3.1/exports/export-formats.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You passed variable correctly. But your the problem is that [Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/blob/3.1/src/Excel.php) contains constant XLSX and it's not a property. Constants can be accessed staticly Excel::XLSX or dynamicly using [constant](http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php) function:

```
     $fileType = $request->input('fileType', 'xlsx');
     $writerType = constant('Excel::' . strtoupper($fileType));
```

Comment: It will get `Couldn't find constant Excel::XLSX`. So I use full namespace: `$writerType = constant('\\Maatwebsite\\Excel\\Excel::' . strtoupper($fileType));` It works! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
 return Excel::create('PatientList',function($excel) use ($variable){

            $excel->sheet('List',function($sheet) use ($variable){
                $sheet->fromArray($variable);
            });

        })->download($type);
```

use like this when you download the file.pass `$type` from your view.